# Whether Euclid considered squares to be rectangles

Tags: geometry, reference-request, education, math-history, quadrilateral

When I look up

> 'that which is right-angled but not equilateral'

there are translations that show the word before the above phrase to '[oblong](http://www2.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/booki/defI22.html)', some that show '[rectangle](http://euclid.trentu.ca/math/sb/3260H/Fall-2017/Euclids-axioms.pdf)' and some that show both with one term in brackets ([1](http://math.bu.edu/people/sr/549-10/handouts/Euclid.pdf) [2](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/euclids-elements-definitions.html) [3](http://www.employees.csbsju.edu/tsibley/Appendix-A.pdf)).

Why is this? Guesses:

1. Translation error
2. Euclid didn't consider squares to be rectangles.
3. Euclid made a mistake.
4. Other

---

Related:

[In Korea, are squares considered rectangles?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/in-korea-are-squares-considered-rectangles)

[Are kindergartners supposed to be steered from squares being rectangles?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13831/)

[In what curricula are “rectangles” defined so as to exclude squares?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13700/in-what-curricula-are-rectangles-defined-so-as-to-exclude-squares)

[Why do we have circles for ellipses, squares for rectangles but nothing for triangles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249741/why-do-we-have-circles-for-ellipses-squares-for-rectangles-but-nothing-for-tria)

[What are/should kids (be) taught about the colour of the sun?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394471)

Comment: Where did you find that phrase? Euclid's elements?

Comment: Oblong is another word for a rectangle of length more than width. I for one would not make simple things more complicated than needed and expend time on it.

Comment: @Arthur Yes! Updated. Thanks.

Comment: @Narasimham Relevance please? My question is why some texts give 'oblong' while others give 'rectangle' or even both words with one in round brackets.

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/oblong  It has a Latin origin, old English, refers to the figure when one dimension is larger than the other. It is meant to specifically exclude the square in its subset reference, which is not the case for the rectangle. About round brackets please refer to explanation of notation in the index pages.

Comment: 5. It was written in ancient Greek 3,000 years ago and math has developed a different rigor and vocabulary since and this question is irrelevant and pointless. If you have a question to ask then *ask* it and stop getting snippy with people giving relevant answers because but can't figure out what you are incapable of expressing.  Some text translate as "oblong" and others as "rectangle" because some people *chose* to translate it that way.  Why? Who knows? Who cares? What matters is how mathematicians choose to formalize their language. Which is precisely what Marasimham and Robert Israel did.

Comment: @fleablood re who cares: my employers insist squares are not rectangles where I am. Looks like all the kindergarten kids in our centre are going to continue to be taught A LIE unless I do something...

Answer (score 3):

In mathematics, the term "rectangle" includes squares.

"Oblong" is rarely used as a mathematical term.

Comment: How does this answer the question please, Robert Israel?

Comment: I thought that was a complete answer.  If you want a better answer be more specific in exactly what you are asking.  "'that which is right-angled but not equilateral" is very awkward and and old fashioned and extremely *vague* wording.  And as to why do some translate with one word and others to another?  Because different people translate them. To make any sense of your question would be to answer what sense do mathematicians use the term.  And the answer is: we use "rectangle" but it also includes squares.  We don't use "oblong".  I think Robert Israel answered *perfectly*.

Comment: Robert Israel, @fleablood, I was supposed to ask about Euclid's elements which one would discover is the source of the quote upon googling, but I guess I should have been explicit. Edited question. Thanks, I guess. Any updates please?

Answer (score 2):

See [Euclid's *Elements*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0086%3Abook%3D1%3Atype%3DDef%3Anumber%3D22):

> **Definition 22**.
>
> Of quadrilateral ([*τετράπλευρος*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%85%CF%81%CE%AC)) figures, a *square* ([*τετράγωνος*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%84%CF%81%CE%AC%CE%B3%CF%89%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%82)) is that which is both equilateral and right-angled; an *oblong* ([*ἑτερομήκης*: with sides of uneven length](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=e%28tero%2Fmhkes&la=greek&can=e%28tero%2Fmhkes0&prior=orqogw/nion&d=Perseus:text:1999.01.0085:book=1:type=Def:number=22&i=1)) that which is right-angled but not equilateral; a *rhombus* that which is equilateral but not right-angled; and a *rhomboid* that which has its opposite sides and angles equal to one another but is neither equilateral nor right-angled. And let quadrilaterals other than these be called *trapezia*.

And see [Heath's commentary](https://books.google.it/books?id=HxhEBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA188), page 188:

> *Tetragonon* was already a square with the Pythagoreans, and it is so most commonly in Aristotle; but in *De anima*, II.3, 414b31 it seems to be a quadrilateral, and in *Metaph*., 1054b2, "equal and equiangular *tetragona*," it cannot be anything else but quadrilateral if "equiangular" is to have any sense. Though, by introducing *tetrapleuron* for any quadrilateral, Euclid enabled ambiguity to be avoided, there seem to be traces of the older vague use of *tetragonon* in much later writers.